# 2 router in cascade with 2 DHCP and remote access

Tags: router

The installation is in a holidays house (so no permanent internet access)
I have a 4g-Routerm (ROUTER-1 = huawei B525-b23) that enable the internet access. I switch it on one day a week.
I have another router (ROUTER-2 = GL-MT300N-V2).

ROUTER-2 is always plugged on electricity.
On ROUTER-2 is connected through ethernet port a Raspberry-Pi3 (with Home Assistant on it).
On ROUTER-2 is connected through WIFI a Camera IP

ROUTER-1 and ROUTER-2 are connected together through ethernet.

When ROUTER-1 is not plug to electricity, none have acces to internet, but it's not an issue.

The camera save picture on the Rapbery Pi3, the Home Assistat is recording some sensor data.

When I switch on the electricity on the ROUTER-1, everyone have access to internet.

What I want is to have remote Access to my router-2 and my Rasberry and my Camera when ROUTER-1 is online

How should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can think of two solutions for this setup but both involve buying a second hand cheap router.

I think the use of a single router would make this setup a lot easier. Any router would work that supports:a USB 4g Modem to be attached to it, and has support for setting up a openvpn server and you need to be OK with leaving the Internet on all the time just make sure you dont have any services running that use up bandwidth and you should be ok. You can can connect both raspberry pi and IP camera to that router. Setup Openvpn server open the UDP port required and download the certificates, You should be able to vpn into your network and manage it through SSH or something remotely.
The second option is tailored to you but still requires swapping the 4G Modem with another one that supports these things: Wake on LAN, openvpn server, supports ssh into it over LAN and either has 4G support through a sim card slot or a usb port with modem support.

You can then have it setup so this new Router-1 is switched off with wake on lan configured on it and the raspberry pi to send the magic packet. You can use something like this to get an idea of how WoL https://www.lifewire.com/wake-on-lan-4149800. You can use cron on your raspberry pi to send WoL signal to Router 1 once a week which would eventually give you internet access once the router is up. You have to setup a vpn server on it and forward the required port and download the certificates. When your scheduled WoL cron runs make sure you are able to connect through vpn then access network resources you wish, at the end when you are done you can ssh into the router-1 and turn it off.

I hope this helps. I had a look at the router models you are using and it doesnt leave you with many options. You can get cheap second hand routers online that support everything that is required.